# Use output of two greps with diff

Tags: grep, diff

How do I make better the following method of comparing certain lines (lines that start with "@") of two files? I feel certain this could be done on one line and without embarrassing temporary files. I am pretty new to Linux so go easy on me! Thanks in advance.

```
grep "^@" myfile1 > temp1
grep "^@" myfile2 > temp2
diff temp1 temp2
```

Comment: Alternatively, it could be more practical to do: diff myfile1 myfile2 | grep "^@"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Bash, you can use `<(...)`, which will handle temporaries (usually implemented as named pipes under the hood) for you:

```
diff <(grep "^@" myfile1) <(grep "^@" myfile2)
```

Comment: They're not named pipes, they're named pipes :)

Comment: @MattJoiner So, Schrödinger's pipes?

Comment: They're not **temporary files** ಠ_ಠ

Comment: They may or may not be named pipes, depending on what the underlying OS supports (e.g. they could be `/dev/fd/...` file descriptors, which are distinct from named pipes), but the benefit is that `bash` manages them and any required setup/cleanup for you.